# What is “initiator anonymous” in network in chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, onelogin

We use OneLogin chrome extension for our application login, But sometimes the page redirects to some weird page upon successful login, while I check the chrome tool I can see the request initiator as "**anonymous**"

Is their a way to figure this out to identify the source which initiated the request?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly:

1. Log in on Page A.
2. Sometimes you get redirected to weird Page B. When you inspect DevTools, you see that the initiator for the main document was "anonymous".

In that case, you could try running `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { debugger; })` in the DevTools Console while you're still on Page A. That'll pause the page before redirecting, and you may be able to inspect the page to get more insight on what's causing the redirect.